# directus: regenerate thumbnails after having manually inserted into directus_files table

Tags: directus

I manually inserted images into my collection table and into directus_files table with matching uuid and filename.
When I click on an item of my collection I can see the image however the thumbnails are broken:

[image: directus broken thumbnails]

I can see that if I manually upload an image through directus admin interface two thumbnails are created in the local folder with an uuid and a double underscore and a random hash I cannot figure out how is made.

Is there any way to regenerate the thumbnails?

Answer (score 1):

Ok found out, you basically have to harness the REST API to regenerate the thumbnails otherwise Directus is not "smart" enough to regenerate them when you open an item from the collection or fallback to the original image.
The thumbnail also uses a strange hash in the filename derived from the creation time and user so you won't find the name explicitly in any table of the database.

The REST API has to be called as follows:

http://localhost:8055/assets/c1982e98-5b6d-4327-807a-2561002029d7?access_token=mytoken&width=60&height=60&quality=80

the access token is created from the user administration panel, the guid is the one in the database associated with the image.
Notice the width and height must be specified in the database table associated with the image otherwise the REST API will return a warning.